# Is Google Cloud Print for Chromium included in Chromium or just Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, chromium

I use Ubuntu Server to run my home router.  I'm switching from an x64 machine to an ARM machine.  One of the things the router does is [manage cloud print jobs via Google Chrome](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2906017?hl=en).  My research didn't find a way to install Chrome on Linux/ARM, so I figured I'd install Chromium for this task.  I'm not sure if this would work.  Is the functionality I want to use included in Chromium as well as in Chrome?

**Edit:**

I'm asking those who have experience in this area.  I'm not asking you to try it out yourself.  Please do not install Chromium and try to get printer proxy working just to answer this question.

Comment: Have you installed it and checked?

Comment: No I haven't.  That's why I asked.  I don't want to get into hours of troubleshooting something that's not possible.

Comment: Is everyone on superuser like @Ramhound?

Comment: this [blog post](http://blog.chromium.org/2010/06/update-on-google-cloud-print.html) from 3 years ago seems to indicate Chromium does have Cloud Print support - _Those who have been following know that we’ve already added preliminary printing support to Chromium OS via Google Cloud Print_

Comment: @edwin we expect a certain amount of research to be done before a question is asked.  I asked a simple question you provided an answer no reason to be rude towards me

Comment: @ramhound, i was rude because, as you pointed out above, you intimated that I did no research.  What exactly do you think research is?  I have set it up before. I have read the instructions, which I have linked to. I've Googled with no success.  If you don't know the answer to the question, just move on to the next one. Don't attack the OP.

Comment: @Edwin - First are you not the author of the question?  Second I only asked a question.  I wanted to get clarification.  I took "is everyone on superuser like @Ramhound" as an insult, an insult thrown, after I asked a simple question looking for additional insight to what you have tried.  Third the feature should have no problem within Chromium.

Comment: @Ramhound,  Please accept my apologies.  I assumed that you were the one who reviewed my question and downvoted it for being OT.  I did put thought into the question, and with the downvote it will get less eyeballs.

Comment: @Edwin - It does not work like that.  This question has recieved no votes to put on hold.  Just because somebody thought the question was unhelpful does not make it a bad question.  Your getting worked up over a single downvote.

Comment: @Ramhound, with all respect, I don't think that your prolific downvoting is helpful to StackExchange.  Few if any share your voting stats either in the ratio of upvotes/downvotes or downvotes/reputation.  Please don't get mad at me, but to avoid being insulted in the future, you may want to reevaluate your practices.

Comment: @Edwin Why do you care how I use my voting powers I almost always provide feedback on questions and answers I vote on.  Furthermore most of my downvotes are on questions that are not on topic and have been locked.  Questions that are on topic always get an upvote.  **I didn't vote on your question.** I was going to post an answer, now I am, not sure I want to bother with the process to document my answer at this point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12512/discussion-between-ramhound-and-edwin)

Answer (score 0):

I have followed instructions at https://support.google.com/a/answer/2906017?hl=en, and receive an error indicating that the graphical interface is not available.  It looks like the headless mode on chromium is broken.

Since Chrome is not available on Linux ARM, it does not appear possible to run a cloud print server on a Linux on ARM system at this time.

Comment: Look into xvfb as it would allow headless xserver.